# .htaccess rewrite url to index and get urldata after folder slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First I want to show the fully working example that does almost what I want:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ index.php?title=$1
```

index.php

```
echo 'title = '.$_GET['title'];
```

REQUEST localhost/php/htaccess2/index.php/test

RESULT title = test

---

Now I want it to work by requesting localhost/php/htaccess2/test

So I changed the .htaccesss to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?title=$1
```

But then it returns the

RESULT title = index.php

and I want it to return title = test

Please help me!

---

I solved it using another flag like QSA
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, changing this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?title=$1 [NC]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?title=$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Try ```print_r($_GET)``` and see what results you get.

Comment: Array ( [title] => index.php ) ... it must be the .htaccess that doesnt get the right data from the (.*)